# Execute all functions in dictionary and convert to dataframe

Tags: python

I have a python dictionary which stores functions like this:

```
def a_func():
    return "aa"
def b_func():
    return "bb"
def c_func():
    return "cc"

func_dict = {
    "a":a_func,
    "b":b_func,
    "c":c_func
}
```

How can I execute those functions efficiently so that I can make a Dataframe out of it like this:
(I guess a loop is not efficient, the final table may contain millions of values)

```
pd.DataFrame( {'a': ["aa", "aa","aa"], 'b': ["bb", "bb", "bb"], "c": ["cc","cc","cc"]})
    a   b   c
0   aa  bb  cc
1   aa  bb  cc
2   aa  bb  cc
```

The dictionary is also not constant, so I would need a solution which could deal with a dict where the function names are different.

So basically I could do something like this, but as I said, I don't think it is efficient

```
df_dict = {}
for i in range(3):
    for item in func_dict:
        if i == 0:
            df_dict[item] = [func_dict[item]()]
        else:
            df_dict[item].append(func_dict[item]())

{'a': ['aa', 'aa', 'aa'], 'b': ['bb', 'bb', 'bb'], 'c': ['cc', 'cc', 'cc']}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? We need more detail. Because it's not clear what your functions actually do and how they are related to your question as they just return constants. And why do you need millions of the same rows?

Comment: The functions generate random synthetic data. I can execute each function with a loop and store the result, but I guess that would not be efficient.

Comment: If you want to call each function multiple times, you *will* need a loop. For 1000 rows for example, you could use `df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [a_func() for _ in range(1000)], "b": [b_func() for _ in range(1000)], "c": [a_func() for _ in range(1000)]})`

Comment: that solution would be good, but the functions will vary. 
So the next dictionary could have only a_func and b_func
I will add this requirement to the description

Comment: numpy might be able to help though,  I'm pretty sure you can use a function to create an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you pretty much have it. I would use a combo of what you have and what @not_speshal suggested in the comments.

```py
rows_to_create = 3
df_dict = {}
for k, v in func_dict.items():
    df_dict[k] = [v() for _ in range(rows_to_create)]
```

A quick comparison of what you have vs the code above creating 100,000,000 rows of data using the functions provided.

Your current code: ~68 seconds
Code above: ~24 seconds

Comment: your solutions looks good, thanks a lot! However, my gut tells me, that there might be a solution out there without an inefficient loop.